# how to access webservice from one project to another project

Tags: asp.net, web-services

i have an project with name called(dbservice layer) which is in path: d:\webservice\DBService. here i have an webservice which connects to DB and returns an object of an class.

once i added an reference here i get an  url:http://localhost:2371/Jobs.svc

now i have another project name (UILayer) whic is in path: E:\School\UILayer
i added an service  reference here with url as  http://localhost:2371/Jobs.svc
**but i get an messgae telling service is unable why is that happening**.

**if both my webserivce layer and ui layer are in same project. then i able to use the webserive in  the ui layer. and  get the required output**

so i wanted to know is there any way we can acesss the webserive from one project to another project

thanks in advance

prince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publish your web service to an actual location and then add a reference using the actual URL not the one served up by visual studio.  What I think is happening is each Visual Studio instance is using a different port so you can't say localhost:2371 for both projects because that is the local port for the instance your running with your original project.

Publish it and then access it via http://localhost/jobs.svc.  You should be able to access it via IE directly without running Visual Studio if you have published it correctly.

The main point is, you have the wrong URL.

Comment: hi Kelsey,
 thanks for the replay. once i publish my webserive i am able to access now in any project.

i tried  with url  http://localhost/jobs.svc it would not hit the service.
 but once i change the url http://localhost:2371/Jobs.svc was able to access the webservice